# Numpy: tile a matrix into a higher dimension, but with scale

Tags: python, numpy

I need to implement the following behavior in NumPy:

```
a = [1, 2, 3]
b = [[1, 0],
     [0, 1]]
c = f(a, b)

> c = [[[1, 0],
        [0, 1]],
       [[2, 0],
        [0, 2]],
       [[3, 0],
        [0, 3]]]
```

I can implement this with `np.outer(a, b.flatten()).reshape(a.shape + b.shape)`, but that is non-obvious and requires a comment to make the intention of the code clear. Is there any built-in function that gives this behavior?

Comment: Use broadcasting and multiply

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In spirit this is like `outer`, but I think the notation is clearer (at least to an experiences `numpy` user):

```
In [366]: a = np.arange(1,4); b=np.eye(2)
In [367]: c = a[:,None,None]*b[None,:,:]
In [368]: c
Out[368]: 
array([[[1., 0.],
        [0., 1.]],

       [[2., 0.],
        [0., 2.]],

       [[3., 0.],
        [0., 3.]]])
```

Possibly even prettier:

```
In [375]: np.einsum('i,jk->ijk',a,b)
Out[375]: 
array([[[1., 0.],
        [0., 1.]],

       [[2., 0.],
        [0., 2.]],

       [[3., 0.],
        [0., 3.]]])
```

Comment: I like to include the leading `None` for sake of human readers. @juanpa.arrivillaga

Comment: Magnanimous, you are.

Comment: thanks, this post motivated me to learn NumPy broadcasting more completely, which I now use often.

Answer (score 4):

The [`outer` method](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.outer.html) on NumPy ufuncs has more convenient treatment of non-1D inputs than `numpy.outer`:

```
In [1]: import numpy
In [2]: a = [1, 2, 3]
In [3]: b = [[1, 0],
   ...:      [0, 1]]
In [4]: numpy.multiply.outer(a, b)
Out[4]: 
array([[[1, 0],
        [0, 1]],
       [[2, 0],
        [0, 2]],
       [[3, 0],
        [0, 3]]])
```

Comment: ... and unlike my solutions it generalizes to other operators. Neat!

Answer (score 3):

The closest to a builtin may be `np.einsum`:

```
>>> np.einsum('i,jk',a,b)
array([[[1, 0],
        [0, 1]],

       [[2, 0],
        [0, 2]],

       [[3, 0],
        [0, 3]]])
```

or perhaps `np.tensordot`:

```
>>> np.tensordot(a, b, ((),()))
array([[[1, 0],
        [0, 1]],

       [[2, 0],
        [0, 2]],

       [[3, 0],
        [0, 3]]])
```